# VS Code extension - Change where the command appears in the context menu

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am using this VS Code [extension](https://github.com/sleistner/vscode-fileutils) and I would like to change where the command appears in the context menu. I can do this by directly modifying the [package.json](https://github.com/sleistner/vscode-fileutils/blob/master/package.json). 
For instance, I added in the `editor/context` list (around line 100), this:

```
{
    "command": "fileutils.renameFile",
    "group": "edit"
}
```

And it worked, I can see the rename command in my context menu but... when there will be an update, I will loose my edits. So I tried to add this piece of code in the `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\settings.json` but it's not working.

How can I customize a VS Code extension and in particular a `editor/context` command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to add [contributions](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points), such as menu items, in `settings.json`.  That can only be done from a `package.json` file provided by an extension.

However, you can create your own small, personal extension fairly easily (see the [tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension)), and its `package.json` can create new menu items that refer to other extensions' commands.  Note the [semantics for ordering](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#Sorting-of-groups) so you can get the new item in the right place.

Here is a `package.json` fragment that can be added to a personal extension in order to add a menu item that calls into [GitLens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens) (duplicating one of its own menu items, just for illustration):

```
  "contributes": {
    "menus": {
      "editor/context": [
        {
          "command": "gitlens.copyMessageToClipboard",
          "group": "1_modification"
        }
      ],
    },
  },
```

Now, the question mentions you want to "**change** where the command appears in the context menu" (emphasis added).  I don't think it is possible to remove a menu item, so if you follow my suggestion, you'll have two entries.

Note: The extension tutorial omits how to install (as opposed to merely test) a personal extension without publishing it on the [marketplace](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery).  I happen to have my own personal extension with [instructions](https://github.com/smcpeak/vscode-smcpeak#installation) on how to install it (mostly for my own reference!).  One detail my instructions do not say is you have to have a `publisher` attribute in `package.json`, but it can be anything.

Comment: why is it not possible to edit other extension's `package.json` to make it work?

Comment: @NitishPrajapati As the OP stated, when the other extension receives an update, any changes you have made to its files will be lost.